# Unrecognized element exceptions after conversion to web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, vs-web-site-project, vs-web-application-project

After converting my `Web Site Project` to a `Web Application Project`, some of my custom controls are missing, and I keep getting an get *unrecognized element* exceptions.

I can't figure out what's going on. I've tried copying over the `web.config` and registering the controls in the page directive, but it's still not working. Do I need to adjust the `web.config` manually, or is it possible that I'm still missing a reference somewhere?

I would appreciate some advice on how to fix this.

Comment: Are the unrecognized elements user controls (`.ascx`) or custom server controls?

Comment: And a +1 to get you off to a better start :)

Comment: Just posted an answer. Check everything I suggested and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It most likely has something to do with the conversion, and I suspect the application namespace. I don't know how thorough the conversion process is, but you might need to update the user control directives and code-behind files.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MyUserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="MyNamespace.MyApplication.Controls.MyUserControl" %>
```

Code-behind:

```
namespace MyNamespace.MyApplication.Controls
{
    public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Also, make sure that the user controls are mapped properly in the `web.config`:

```
<pages>
    <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="Custom" src="~/controls/myusercontrol.ascx" tagName="MyUserControl" />
        ...
    </controls>
</pages>
```

Comment: That dosen't seem to have done the trick I have fixed other errors and added namespaces. Is it required that I use Config Transformers?

Comment: I also had to move all my dll's to the Bin, still having other troubles but that's for another post. TY!